# Calling UserDefined Functions in ExtJs

Tags: extjs

I am new to ExtJs,i have designed an entry form as follows,

```
var HouseForm = new Ext.FormPanel({     
        renderTo: "HouseCreation",
        frame: true,
        url: url+'/lochweb/loch/house/persist', 
        title: 'Create House',
        bodyStyle: 'padding:5px',           
        width: 500,
        items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Name',
                name: 'name',
                allowBlank:false
                },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'TaxId',
                name: 'taxId',              
                allowBlank:true
                }
    });

    var win = new Ext.Window({
        layout:'fit',
        closable: false,
        resizable: true,
        plain: true,
        border: false,
        items: [HouseForm]
    });
    win.show();
    });
```

I need to validate the user inputs manually,so i need to call my function to validate the user inputs.how to **define and call** a function and also is there any other layout other than **fit**?

Thanks

Comment: which version of ExtJS are you using?

Comment: I think its 4.0.7 and not 4.7

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write your functions/methods in same .js file and call them as usual i.e. () . It will work.

About layouts, there many varieties of layouts available in ExtJS. [Here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) is the link which shows example and minimal code of all the layouts possible in ExtJS.

Comment: Thanks for the comment,can i call as follows,vtype='validate();' where validate() is an user defined function

Comment: you dont have to include validate() inside single quotes. only vtype=validate(); will work.